# Run function only when data changes

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I am running an ajax call every 3 seconds to update data in my app (information changes that quickly). Inside the $.done() callback, I run an expensive function that is slowing down my app. I would like to only run this function if the data returned from ajax is different from what I already have in the data object. What is the best "vue" way to do this?

```js
var app = new Vue({
  data: {
    people : []
  },
  methods: {
    loadPeople() {
        $.ajax({
            method: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            url: base_url + 'users/getParticipants2/' + event_id
        }).done(data => {
        //this.people is an array
        //data is an array
        //I only want to do these two things if data is different from what I had in this.people previously
            this.people = data;  
            this.filterPeople();
        });
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: depends on what `data` is

Comment: so look for differences.....

Comment: @epascarello is there a "vue" way to do this? I'd rather stick within the framework when possible

Comment: One method is to request just an 'Etag' header, which sends just a header and not the payload. If the Etag is different, the data is different, so then you'd request the data. Here's an article with several ideas, depending on your needs: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/increasing-application-performance-with-http-cache-headers

Comment: I love Vue but why does everything have to be "the vue way"?  Use the right tool for the job.

Answer (score 1):

Vue actually has something that may help you here. [Vue has a `looseEqual` function used internally](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/blob/v2.5.16/dist/vue.js#L284-L315). It is [exported as `_q`](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/blob/v2.5.16/dist/vue.js#L3954) and can be used as `this._q()`.

You can leverage it to just update your property when the fetched data is different from what you already have. See demo below.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    people: []
  },
  methods: {
   async fetchPeople() {
     let response = await axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users');
      if (this._q(this.people, response.data)) {
        console.log("data didn't change, not updating");
        return;
      }
      console.log("data changed, updating");
      this.people = response.data;
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <button @click="fetchPeople">Fetch People</button>
  <ul>
    <li v-for="p in people">{{ p.name }}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

The drawback is that it is an internal function (the `_` prefix is for that) so it may change in the future. Its implementation used to be

```
function looseEqual(o1, o2) {
    return JSON.stringify(o1) === JSON.stringify(o2);
}
```

So you can always fall back for that.

Answer (score 0):

Based off your explanation and the naming conventions used in your code snippet I do have some fundamental suggestions that may, or may not, be helpful.

If your filterPeople() function is primarily concerned with filtering and updating your view, then you might be approaching this the wrong way.

Without knowing what the filterPeople() function actually does I can only suggest that if you are actually running some type of filter, then you should actually define a vue.js filter. Let's say you want to run the filterPeople filter on the list of returned participants.

```
Vue.filter('filterPeople', function (newer, older) {
   if (older == newer) {
       return older
    }

    // Otherwise filter, and return 'newer' 

 });

var endpoint  = '/users/participants';

new Vue ({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        participants: null,
        previous: null
    },
    methods:{
        getParticipants: function(){
               this.$http.get(endpoint).then(function(response){
                   this.previous = this.particpants;
                   this.participants = response.data;
                }, 
                function(error){
                  console.log(error.statusText);
                }
              })
          },
          mounted: function () {
            this.getParticipants();
         }
  });
```

Then your html would look something like the following.

```
<div id="app">
     {participants | filterPeople(previous)}
<div>
```

That would be my recommended way (is psuedo code, but you get the picture).  Another way would be usimg a v-if directive to either show the binding with and without the filter.

Additionally, you are referencing a getParticipants endpoint but using an HTTP post method.  Generally, I would recommend that the endpoint be named /users/participants with a GET method that returns the participants, and a POST method (to the same endpoint) with a JSON request body that creates a participant (or something similar).  A getParticpants endpoint is poor naming, you generally don't want to have an endpoint be named after an action, but rather it should simply be named after the resource.  Web service "methods" are more of a SOAP thing.